How many $n$ such that $\gcd(n,1)+\gcd(n,2)+\gcd(n,3)=\gcd(n,4)$
How many positive integers $1 \leq n \leq 2023$ satisfy the equation:
$$\gcd(n,1)+\gcd(n,2)+\gcd(n,3)=\gcd(n,4)$$My attempt goes as follows, let's denote $s=\gcd(n,1)+\gcd(n,2)+\gcd(n,3)$ and $d=\gcd(n,4)$. We can see $s>2$ and thus $d>2$.
Because $d \vert 4 \implies d=4$. Which means (because d is the $\gcd$) $n=4k$ for some integer $k$.
Moreover, $$s=1+2+\gcd(n,3)=4 \implies \gcd(n,3)=1$$
Thus $3\nmid n$.
So far $4 \vert n$ and $3\nmid n$ where $1 \leq n \leq 2023$. How should I proceed from here?

You are already done. Exactly the positive integers $n$ with $n=4k$ and $3\nmid n$ satisfy he equation. So $4,8,16,20,\ldots, 2020$. Just count!

Should I use Inclusion-Exclusion? Or just plain-old (multiple of $4$) - (multiple of $3$)?

Firstly, count of numbers divisible by $4$
$$\left\lfloor \frac{2023}{4} \right\rfloor = 505$$
Then, count of numbers divisible by both $4$ and $3$ (LCM of $4$ and $3$ is $12$):
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{2023}{12} \right\rfloor = 168$$
At last, applying the principle of inclusion-exclusion:
$$
505 - 168 = 337
$$
Thus, the answer is $337.$

Had a feeling that I have to use Inclusion-Exclusion, thanks!

$$\text{Please do not type like this.}$$

Okay, Thanks for your advice.
